# Setter methods, multiple with no parameters or single with value?

Tags: java, javabeans, standards, getter-setter

I'm working on a java based game with a friend and I've noticed he's taking an approach that concerns me, in terms of maintainability.

For a class representing a playable `Character`, instead of just creating 1 method which sets an object's property, he's creating separate methods which set the property to a specific value.

Which of these 2 options would be the best to follow going forward?

- Option 1

  ```
  public void runFast() {
      this.character.speed = 5.0f
  }

  public void walk() {
      this.character.speed = 2.0f
  }

  public void stop() {
      this.character.speed = 0.0f;
  }
  ```
- Option 2

  ```
  public void setSpeed(float speedTemp) {
      this.character.speed = speedTemp;
  }
  ```

Comment: both ! add ur methods and add a generic setter method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an enum to set the speed - then you can still have

```
void setSpeed(Speed speed) {
  this.character.speed = speed.getAmount();
}
```

with:

```
enum Speed {
  FAST(5.0f), WALK(2.0f), STOP(0.0f);

  private final float amount;
  private Speed(flaot a) { this.amount = a; }
  public float getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }
}
```

That way, you can quickly update the values, but still have a predefined amount. Its flexible and easy to maintain. You might want to save the enum instead of the float.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best option would be to declare constants/enums, and use the option 2.

---

**Example (constants) :**

```
public static final float STOP = 0.0f;
public static final float WALK = 2.0f;
public static final float FAST = 5.0f;

setSpeed(STOP|WALK|FAST);
```

---

**Example (enums) :**

```
public enum Speed
{
    FAST(5.5f),
    STOP(0),
    WALK(2.5f);

    float value;

    Speed(float pValue)
    {
        this.value = pValue;
    }

    public float getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}

setSpeed(Speed.FAST);
```

Comment: Is this using Consts or are you trying to explain Enums? setSpeed(STOP|WALK|FAST);

Answer (score 1):

My Solution would be to use Enums instead,

it is cleaner and has more context and easily extensible if you have more to do with your speed maxHeartRate in the future.

```
public class Character {

    private Speed speed;

    public Speed getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(Speed speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
};



public enum Speed {

    STOP(0),

    RUN(5.5),

    WALK(2.5);

    double value;

    Speed(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. For example

- Are speeds limited to a few predefined values? In that case using an `enum` would be a good solution.
- Is walking / running / stopping going have side effects other than just setting the speed? As a contrived example, starting to run might cause the character to drop an item it's holding, or stopping might cause the character to skid a little. In this case having separate methods might make sense.
- Or maybe there are only a few predefined states, but depending on the environment running speed might be different.

What it comes down to is: Which way of conceptually modeling the properties of your character works best for your game logic / physics? Work this out and then base the interface of your classes on that. Don't get too hung up on the exact API early on, this sort of stuff is pretty easy to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

getter and setters are useful when you want that your code is readble and for avoiding that public class fields can be used in the wrong way from another classes.
This example show how is important.

CLASS A:

```
 public class ClassA{     
 // in the body class
 private String fieldClass1;

//classic setter
public void setfieldClass1(String f1)
{
 fieldClass1 = f1;
}
```

}

CLASS B:

```
public class ClassB{   
// in the bodyclass
public String fieldClass2;

//classic setter
public void setfieldClass2(String f2)
{
 setfieldClass2 = f2; 
}
```

CLASS C:

```
public class ClassC{

//in the body of the class this method use class a and class b
public void calc()
{
 ClassA aObject = new ClassA();
 ClassB bObject = new ClassB();
 ClassA.fieldClass1 = 5 + 5; // illegal expression for the compiler and costrain the developer to use setters
 ClassB.fieldClass2 = 8 + 8; // legal expression
}
 }
```

This mean that you must define a "modifiers logic" (protected, private, public) before make setters and getters. Define before the modifiers and after define the setters and getters.